# linq jsonresult dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, linq, jsonresult

I'm populating a dropdownlist of years using the following controller.  Instead of listing years manually, I want to retrieve a list from the database.  I created a linq query and have returned the years to a list, but I can't figure out how to get that list into the one being passed.

```
    public JsonResult PopulateYears()
    {
        var list = new object[] { };

        list = new object[] {
            new { value = 2001, name = "2001" },
            new { value = 2002, name = "2002" },
            new { value = 2003, name = "2003" }
        };

        var results = dbBudget.Estimates.Select(o => o.Year).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            //How do I create entries for list here?
        }

        return Json(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create an anonomus type like such

```
var list = (from x in dbBudget.Estimates.Select(o => o.Year).Distinct()
select new {value=x.Year,name = x.Year});
```

and then just use your line

```
return Json(list);
```

the result will be

```
[{"name":"2011","value":"2011"},{"name":"2012","value":"2012"},{"name":"2010","value":"2010"}]
```

Comment: The presence of Select(o => o.Year) prevents me from specifying x.Year for value and name.  If I remove Select(o => o.Year), I can specify x.Year, but I'm not getting distinct year values.

Comment: This did the trick: var list = (from o in dbBudget.Estimates
                        select new { value = o.Year, name = o.Year }).Distinct();

Comment: @MattEllenburg Sorry I was too quick in the response and didn't test my code. I thought the `.Select()` was allowed in a LINQ Query. I have learnt something new here too.